# How do i get selected Value from daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to get startDate and endDate after selected from datepicker with the following code so i can do ajax call back but nothing gets printed.

Here is the HTML part?

```
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
       <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down">
   </i>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery part

```
   $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }

    }, cb).on("change", function() {

 $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({ opens: 'left' }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("Your Select date range is: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });


});

    cb(start, end);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using daterangepicker's `apply.daterangepicker` [event](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#events). Below is a demonstration of the same to get selected start and end date of daterangepicker upon range selection.

```js
$(function () {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb).on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        var startDate = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var endDate = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        console.log(`startDate = ${startDate}, endDate = ${endDate}`);
    });

    cb(start, end);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-XKa9Hemdy1Ui3KSGgJdgMyYlUg1gM+QhL6cnlyTe2qzMCYm4nAZ1PsVerQzTTXzonUR+dmswHqgJPuwCq1MaAg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-mh+AjlD3nxImTUGisMpHXW03gE6F4WdQyvuFRkjecwuWLwD2yCijw4tKA3NsEFpA1C3neiKhGXPSIGSfCYPMlQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-P5MgMn1jBN01asBgU0z60Qk4QxiXo86+wlFahKrsQf37c9cro517WzVSPPV1tDKzhku2iJ2FVgL67wG03SGnNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-rBi1cGvEdd3NmSAQhPWId5Nd6QxE8To4ADjM2a6n0BrqQdisZ/RPUlm0YycDzvNL1HHAh1nKZqI0kSbif+5upQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
       <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down">
   </i>
</div>
```